# List users on remote mac for SSH / VNC login

Tags: mac, network, ssh, remote-desktop, remote-control

I have a mini-mac on my local network with `remote login` and `screen sharing` turned on, and have the password to one of the users login. Problem is, I can't currently connect it to a screen via HDMI (to see the user names), and I don't remember the correct user name.
Being able to list user accounts given the mac's Host Name / IP would be really handy.

Is it possible to list the user names of a remote mac before having remote shell access?

Comment: I don't understand this statement:   *Problem is, I can't get it connected to a screen via HDMI, and I don't remember the correct user name.*  What does HDMI have to do with this?"  Also, unless you have access to the Mac, you won't be able to get a list of users with access; if you could, it wouldn't be very secure.

Comment: Being able to connect to a screen would allow me to see the users available for login, or simply log in and use the mac mini locally. I wanted to emphasize the fact that I do have *Physical* and *Network* access to the machine, and also have the password, but do not have the user name, or a *User Interface* access in order to obtain the user name. Why would having a list of users be insecure? Isn't that what passwords are meant for?

Comment: Ok...so for whatever reason, you can't log on locally with a keyboard and screen.  It will not output a list of user accounts for you.  It's not secure, because that's 50% of your login credential right there.  Also, keep in mind that what you see on the login screen isn't your username.  My "name" is "Allan" on my Mac, but it's definitely not my user name; it's something else entirely.  You need to log in locally.

Comment: I am more familiar with Windows, where there's the `wmic.exe /node:"HOSTNAME" ComputerSystem Get UserName` option. I figured there would be something similar for mac. Thanks anyway.